# How to crop an Image/Video n Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW1Tp.jpg)I want to crop the above imge in 3 dimension or something like that, as drawn.

I tried this in opencv

`crop_img = img[y: y+h, x:x+h]`...But it only crops image in a simple rectangle...I think my image cannot be cropped by simple rectangle.

Comment: You want to crop a flat 2-d image in 3-d? Are we to guess the third dimension? And is it time or depth?

Comment: Hey John doe, welcome to stack overflow. and welcome to computer vision too. You have a flat 2d image. It can never be 3d. but i understand your point, that it is not a flat rectangle, but a slightly tilted rectangle without constant width height ?

Comment: If you want to segment the street (crop it), you need to have a mask and select those pixels, this cropped image will nevertheless be inside a rectangular image with the rest of the pixels black or any other color

Comment: Sorry. Yes it's a 2D image.

Comment: I edited the image ...see new image

Comment: You mean you want to crop the image in trapezoid fashion?

Comment: Yes :) Correct.

Comment: You can create a contour with all your points/major of your points of the lines (all 4 sides). The fill the contour with black/pixels .. This acts as a mask. Then do a bitwise and operation to extract the region.

Comment: Can you please give me some idea? I created a black mask using photoshop

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach.

```
mask = np.zeros((w, h), np.uint8)
# Set pixels you want to keep to 1
crop_img[mask == 0] = 0
```

This is for grayscale images. For RGB images you would use `crop_img[mask == 0] = (0, 0, 0)`